# analyzing complexity of recursive algorithm with uneven division

Tags: algorithm, recursion, code-analysis

I was asked to analyze the time complexity of the following recursive equation using the iterative method:

> T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n^2.
>
> T(1)=1

when I try to expand the equation it blows up and I can't really keep track of all the recursive "calls" and constants.
This is caused by the uneven division of the data (1\3 - 2\3).

Is there an easier way to solve this using the iterative method?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use Akra–Bazzi method to find the solution first..

Comment: Have you tried google searching this exact equation?

Comment: T(1)=1
(forgot to mention it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be O(n^2) if I haven't missed anything...

First of all T grows monotonously (for several first values you can check this manually, for the rest it's by induction - if a function is monotonous in [1..10], then it will be monotonous on [1..15] and so on).

```
T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n^2<=2T(2n/3)+n^2
T(n)<=n^2+2*(2n/3)^2+4*(4n/9)^2+...
     =sum[k=0..log3(n)]((8/9)^k*n^2)
     =n^2*sum[k=0..log3(n)](8/9)^k
    <=n^2*sum[k=0..inf](8/9)^k
    <=C*n^2
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to this, but, can we always assume the bigger part takes longer than the smaller one?
(I see you upper-bounded the original sequence with 2T(2n/3))

Comment: @user2190298: I've added explanation about monotonousness, is it clear?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/alglectures/skiena.lectures/lecture3.2.pdf) is a paper that shows the analysis of a similiar formula: T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n

One way to make it iterative will require using a method similar to how parsers\compilers work

Applying your formula: T(n)=T(n/3)+T(2n/3)+n^2 with n = 1..9 yields

```
T(0) = 0

T(1) = T(1/3) + T(2/3) + 1

T(2) = T(2/3) + T(4/3) + 4

T(3) = T(1) + T(2) + 9

T(4) = T(4/3) + T(8/3) + 16

T(5) = T(5/3) + T(10/3) + 25

T(6) = T(2) + T(4) + 36

T(7) = T(7/3) + T(14/3) + 49

T(8) = T(8/3) + T(16/3) + 64

T(9) = T(3) + T(6) + 91

T(3m) = T(m) + T(2m) + 9m^2
```

.. Maybe this can give you some hints

Answer (score 0):

What helps here is to not multiply out any of the numbers, but write everything in terms of powers. Doing that all by hand, I got the following for the first few expansions:

```
T(n) = T((1/3)n) + T((2/3)n) + n^2
     =    T((1/3^2)n) 
       + 2T((2/3^2)n) 
       +  T((2^2/3^2)n) 
       + [n^2]                      #constants from the first expansion
       + [((1/3)n)^2 + ((2/3)n)^2]  #constants from the second expansion
     =    T((1/3^3)n) 
       + 3T((2/3^3)n) 
       + 3T((2^2/3^3)n) 
       +  T((2^3/3^3)n) 
       + [n^2] 
       + [((1/3)n)^2 + ((2/3)n)^2] 
       + [((1/3^2)n)^2 + ((2/3^2)n)^2 + ((2^2/3^2)n)^2] #constants from 3rd expansion
```

It's a bit hard to tell, but what seems to happen is that you get the binomial coefficients going for the `T`s, where the `x`th expansion looks like this:

```
T(n) = sum((x choose i) * T(((2^i)/(3^x))n), i from 0 to x)
       + constants
```

At each step, the additional constants that are added at expansion `x` are the arguments to `T` from expansion `x-1`, squared, since they all end up getting squared thanks to the `n^2`. So all the *new* constants at a given expansion `y` are equal to:

```
NewConsts(y) = sum(((y - 1) choose i) * (((2^i)/(3^(y-1)))*n)^2, i from 0 to y - 1)
```

And *all* the constants at expansion `x` are equal to

```
n^2 + sum(NewConsts(y), y from 1 to x)
```

So, assuming all the above is correct, which I'm not 100% sure on, I guess you have to figure out when the constants stop mattering - that is, for what `x` is `((2^x / 3^x) * n)^2)` equal to 0 - and your answer is the sum of all of those constants...